# Laravel database Insert error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I trying to insert data to database using *laravel 4 eloquent model*. But throws the error:

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::save() "
```

I am new to laravel don't know where I Have gone wrong.

**my UsersController.php code**

```
public function postRequest() { 
    $request = new Request;
    $request->vms = Input::get('vms');
    $request->location = Input::get('location');
    $request->descr = Input::get('descr');
    $request->status = Input::get('status');
    $request->save();
}
```

**My Request.php Model**

```
<?php

class Request extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'requests';
    protected $fillable = array('vms', 'location', 'descr', 'status');

    public function ruser() {
        return $this->hasOne('Ruser'); // this matches the Eloquent model
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Request model name conflicts with Laravel Request class. You have two options:

1) Namespace your model:

```
<?php namespace App;

class Request extends Eloquent {

  ...

}
```

Then use it as:

```
$request = new App\Request;
```

2) Rename your model.

Comment: Ah you beat me by the minute:)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your hitting the laravel "Request" facade, instead of your Request model.

Could you try to prefix your new class call with the correct namespaces?

```
$request = new yourname\yourpackage\Request();
```

Or, best of all, call it something else?